# Forgot to enable hierarchical updates on my Nominatim database. How can I fix stale data?

Tags: openstreetmap, osmosis, nominatim

I have been running a Nominatim server for a few months. The server is updated with Osmosis. Over time, I have seen my data slowly get out of date. I believe the reason is that I forgot to enable hierarchical updates, causing certain places to miss out on updates. Is there some way to fix this, say by telling Osmosis to reprocess all updates for the last two months, or do I need to completely reimport the database?